# How can I get POST variable form HTTP header with java?

Tags: java, http, post

```
 Socket client = ss.accept();           
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());
            out.print("HTTP/1.1 200 \r\n"); 
            out.print("Content-Type: text/HTML\r\n");
            out.print("\r\n");


            out.print("<form method='POST' action=''>First name: <input type='text' name='FirstName' value='Mickey'><br><input type='submit' value='Submit'></form>"
                    + "\r\n");

            String line;

            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                if(line.length() == 0) {
                    break;
                }    
                 System.out.println(line);
            }
            System.out.println("lõpp");
            out.close();
            in.close();
            client.close();
```

this code gives me this after pressing submit.

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 16
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Origin: http://localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: et,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cookie: s_ncomui_ev14=%5B%5B%27link%27%2C%271423849771968%27%5D%5D
```

There should be one balnk line and my POST variables. in.readLine() just blocks the code. Browswer just keeps loading. I have to stop it manualy.

Comment: Once you open the client inputstream, it is too late to post your stuff. You've also got additional problems (like the in.readLine() issue)...

Comment: it loads form and after that I can press submit